# Failed to execute goal org.apache.karaf.tooling:karaf-maven-plugin:4.1.1:verify (verify)

Tags: apache-karaf

When i am trying to build the project using maven ,getting this error .Can any one help me sort this out?

Failed to execute goal org.apache.karaf.tooling:karaf-maven-plugin:4.1.1:verify (verify)

Answer (score 0):

The Apache Karaf feature verification fails.  You don't provide any useful information, so it's hard to tell what's going wrong, but the most common cause is that an OSGi bundle's requirement can not be satisfied.  It's either a missing package or a missing service, and in both cases, you need to add a dependency to a bundle providing a capability that can match the requirement.